# vim ultisnip expanding after the line break

Tags: vim, ultisnips

I use Ultisnips in vim a lot together with vim-expand:

```
snippet prg 
!This is file : `!v expand('%:r')`
! Author= `!v expand($USER)`
! Started at: `date +%d.%m.%y`
! 
Program  ${1:`!v expand('%:r')`}
Implicit None
${2:<++Start Typing++>}
End Program  $1
endsnippet
```

I am facing a problem that, after the ${1:} is expanded in 
${1:`!v expand('%:r')`}, if I put a linebreak, the $1 in `End Program $1` is  picking that up as well; which in NOT intended.
To make it clear, here is a screencast: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IjoqWXQNI8

I want to expand and match the first line, but not after linebreak.
kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is something already covered by the screencast for [**Ultisnips**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_WQxYgK0Pk). All you need is regex adjustment to your snippet value `$1`

```
Program  ${1:`!v expand('%:r')`}
Implicit None
${2:<++Start Typing++>}
End Program  ${1/([^\n$]+).*/$1/}
endsnippet

${1/([^\n$]+).*/$1/}
        |     |  |
        |     |  +--------Replace by first atom i.e. Matched by (..)
        |     +--------Anything That follows.
        +----------- Match everything except a newline | EOL(endofline)
```